# Read a source code from web page and extract some data from it

Tags: regex, vbscript

I want to read a source code from web page and extract some data from it.
I used here in my example a RegEx for extracting the data, but i didn't get 
any data, perhaps this is due from unicode or the pattern dosn't match ?
When i test this pattern with RegExBuddy it match, but in vbscript no ?
Perhaps, i miss something in the code, or i must re-write by another way ?

Here is my try :

```
Option Explicit
Dim URL,fso,ws,LogFile,sSrcUrl,oHTTP,bGetAsAsync,Data
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "txt"
if fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then 
    fso.DeleteFile LogFile
end If

sSrcUrl = "https://fr.giveawayoftheday.com/"
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
bGetAsAsync = False
oHTTP.open "GET", sSrcUrl, bGetAsAsync
oHTTP.send
If oHTTP.status <> 200 Then
WScript.Echo "unexpected status = " & oHTTP.status & vbCrLf & oHTTP.statusText
WScript.Quit
End If
Data = oHTTP.responseText
WriteLog Data,LogFile
wscript.echo Extract(Data)
'****************************************************************
Function Extract(Data)
    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
    set oRE = New RegExp
    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
    oRE.Global = True
    oRE.MultiLine = True
    oRE.Pattern = "<div class=""giveaway_wrap cf"">(\r.*\n.*){17}</div>"
    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data)
    If not isEmpty(oMatches) then
        For Each Match in oMatches   
            Line = Match.Value
            Extract = Line
        Next
    End if 
End Function
'*****************************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile)
    Dim fs,ts 
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForWriting,True,-1)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'*****************************************************************
```

So the result that i expect is :

```
<div class="giveaway_wrap cf">
                <div class="giveaway_img">
                    <img src="https://giveawayoftheday.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/82810932353ab590bf475ea3980f3038.png" alt="Excel Url Validator 1.0 Giveaway" />
                    <div class="giveaway_label">
                        <a href="https://fr.giveawayoftheday.com/excel-url-validator-1-0/" class="label_link"></a>
                        <div class="old_price">$40.00</div>
                        <div class="free">
                            <span class="big">GRATUIT</span> aujourd’hui
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="over">
                    <div class="giveaway_title">
                        <a href="https://fr.giveawayoftheday.com/excel-url-validator-1-0/">Excel Url Validator 1.0</a>
                        <div class="giveaway_date">16 octobre 2017</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="giveaway_descr">Excel Url Validator trouve des liens rompus dans les feuilles de calcul Excel.</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: There is another (and better) way: Use an HTML parser.  Using regex alone will quickly fail here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you show me how ? Thank you !

Comment: I don't know VB well enough to be useful to you.  But I upvoted you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for the upvote and i don't know why people here downvote something that is well explained in my case ? or at least explain to me why this must be downvoted ?

Comment: Questions seeking to use regex to parse HTML get asked way too often here and I guess it annoys people.  But the question of how to parse HTML with VB is legitimate.

Comment: you could [convert the html to xhtml](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/xml-hacks/0596007116/ch02s13.html) then use your regular XML parser on the result

Comment: @Hackoo how did you copy the value from `oHTTP.responseText` into RegExBuddy for testing? Did you save it to a file?

Comment: @omegastripes i just copy and paste the source code from the web site manually to test with RegExBuddy, but when i try to save to a file with vbscript dosen't work with RegExBuddy

Comment: @Hackoo could you please post the code which you use to save to a file. How did you copy the source code from the web site manually? I guess you copied it from DOM in browser, so `<div class="giveaway_wrap cf">` might be dynamically created.

Comment: @omegastripes  Yes i mean i copied from the browser this what i mean ;
Please check my last edit !

Comment: @Hackoo so, have you succeeded with pattern for saved file in RegExBuddy?

Comment: @omegastripes check my anwser ! Now is working like a charm !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution like that :

```
Option Explicit
Dim URL,fso,ws,LogFile,sSrcUrl,oHTTP,bGetAsAsync,Data
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "htm"
if fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then 
    fso.DeleteFile LogFile
end If

sSrcUrl = "https://fr.giveawayoftheday.com/"
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
bGetAsAsync = False
oHTTP.open "GET", sSrcUrl, bGetAsAsync
oHTTP.send
If oHTTP.status <> 200 Then
WScript.Echo "unexpected status = " & oHTTP.status & vbCrLf & oHTTP.statusText
WScript.Quit
End If
Data = oHTTP.responseText
WriteLog Extract(Data),LogFile
wscript.echo Extract(Data)
'****************************************************************
Function Extract(Data)
    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
    set oRE = New RegExp
    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
    oRE.Global = True
    oRE.MultiLine = True
    oRE.Pattern = "<div class=""giveaway_wrap cf"">(?:(?!""giveaway_counter first"">)[\s\S])*</div>"
    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data)
    If not isEmpty(oMatches) then
        For Each Match in oMatches   
            Line = Match.Value
            Extract = Line
        Next
    End if 
End Function
'*****************************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile)
    Dim fs,ts 
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForWriting,True,-1)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'*****************************************************************
```

***Edit on 29/10/2017***

Code updated to popup a HTA file showing the Giveaway of the day

```
Option Explicit
Dim URL,fso,ws,LogFile,sSrcUrl,oHTTP,bGetAsAsync,HTA,Data
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "hta"
if fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then 
    fso.DeleteFile LogFile
end If

If IsInternetConnected = True Then
    If Lang = True Then
        sSrcUrl = "https://fr.giveawayoftheday.com/"
    Else
        sSrcUrl = "https://www.giveawayoftheday.com/"
    End if
End If

Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
bGetAsAsync = False
oHTTP.open "GET", sSrcUrl, bGetAsAsync
oHTTP.send
If oHTTP.status <> 200 Then
WScript.Echo "unexpected status = " & oHTTP.status & vbCrLf & oHTTP.statusText
WScript.Quit
End If
Data = oHTTP.responseText
HTA = "<html>" & vbCrLf &_
"<title>Giveaway of the day by Hackoo</title>" & vbCrLf &_
"<head>" & vbCrLf &_
"<HTA:APPLICATION" & vbCrLf &_
  "APPLICATIONNAME=""GiveAway of the Day""" & vbCrLf &_
  "Icon=DxDiag.exe" & vbCrLf &_
  "BORDER=""thin""" & vbCrLf &_
  "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""no""" & vbCrLf &_
  "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""no""" & vbCrLf &_
  "SCROLL=""no""" & vbCrLf &_
  "SINGLEINSTANCE=""yes""" & vbCrLf &_
  "CONTEXTMENU=""no""" & vbCrLf &_
  "SELECTION=""no""/>" & vbCrLf &_
"<SCRIPT language=""VBScript"">" & vbCrLf &_
"Sub Window_OnLoad" & vbCrLf &_
    "window.resizeTo 450,380" & vbCrLf &_
    "WindowLeft = (window.screen.availWidth - 450)" & vbCrLf &_  
    "WindowTop  = (window.screen.availHeight - 380)" & vbCrLf &_
    "window.moveTo WindowLeft, WindowTop" & vbCrLf &_
"end sub" & vbCrLf &_
"</script>" & vbCrLf &_
"</head>" & vbCrLf &_
"<center>" & vbCrLf &_
"<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=UTF-8"" />" & vbCrLf &_
"<meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=edge"">" & vbCrLf &_
"<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""https://www.giveawayoftheday.com/css/main.css"" />"
WriteLog HTA,LogFile
WriteLog Extract(Data),LogFile
WriteLog "</html>",LogFile
ws.run LogFile
'****************************************************************
Function Extract(Data)
    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
    set oRE = New RegExp
    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
    oRE.Global = True
    oRE.MultiLine = True
    oRE.Pattern = "<div class=""giveaway_wrap cf"">(?:(?!""giveaway_counter first"">)[\s\S])*</div>"
    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data)
    If not isEmpty(oMatches) then
        For Each Match in oMatches   
            Line = Match.Value
            Extract = Line
        Next
    End if 
End Function
'*****************************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile)
    Dim fs,ts 
    Const ForAppending = 8
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForAppending,True,-1)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'*****************************************************************
Function Lang()
Dim sComputer,oWMI,colOperatingSystems,oOS,iOSLang
    sComputer = "."
    Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
        & sComputer _
        & "\root\cimv2")
Set colOperatingSystems = oWMI.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each oOS in colOperatingSystems
    iOSLang = oOS.OSLanguage
Next
If (iOSLang = 1036) Then
    Lang = True
Else
    Lang = False
End If
End Function
'*****************************************************************
Function IsInternetConnected()
Dim MyLoop,strComputer,objPing,objStatus
IsInternetConnected = False
MyLoop = True
While MyLoop = True
    strComputer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\").ExecQuery _
    ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strComputer & "'")
    For Each objStatus in objPing
        If objStatus.Statuscode = 0 Then
            MyLoop = False
            IsInternetConnected = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Check your internet connection !",vbExclamation,"Check your internet connection !"
    Pause(10) 'To sleep for 10 secondes
Wend
End Function
'******************************************************************
 Sub Pause(NSeconds)
    Wscript.Sleep(NSeconds*1000)
 End Sub
'******************************************************************
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome excluding pattern!

Comment: @omegastripes Check the updated version ==> Code updated to popup a HTA file showing the Giveaway of the day